# Python 3.9 caused TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I am converting python 2.7 to python 3.9 with pandas 1.1.5 currently. The below code working in python 2.7 but caused an error when it is in 3.9 (or due to upgrading pandas as well)

```
agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': agent}
query = requests.get('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=AALI.JK')
data = query.json()
data = pd.DataFrame(data['quoteResponse']['result'])
data['regularMarketTime']= pd.to_datetime(data['regularMarketTime'],unit='s').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
data = data[['regularMarketTime','symbol','regularMarketOpen','regularMarketDayHigh','regularMarketDayLow','regularMarketPrice','regularMarketVolume']]
data_append.append(data)
```

The error as below
`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'`
in line `data = pd.DataFrame(data['quoteResponse']['result'])`. Why the error occurred and how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think `data = pd.DataFrame(data.loc['quoteResponse']['result'])` could work, let me know if it did

EDIT:

do this before, to turn the dictionary into a dataframe, and then you can use `.loc`

`pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)`

Comment: It does not work with `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'loc'`. It is due to data is in dict after `data = query.json()`

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with python 3.9 with pandas 1.1.5.
By running python 3.8 with pandas 1.1.5 fix the issue